# Is this the right way to create / destroy string in loop?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Just curious if this is the way to do this, just want to make sure its not leaking, although I would think I am only modifying the string contents.

```
NSMutableString *newPath = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for(fileName in [manager enumeratorAtPath:rootPath]){
    if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqual:@"exr"]) {
        [fileArray addObject:fileName];

        // THIS BIT 
        [newPath setString:rootPath];
        [newPath appendString:@"/"];
        [newPath appendString:fileName];
        // HERE
        attrDir = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:newPath error:&myError];

        fileSize = [attrDir objectForKey: @"NSFileSize"];
        NSLog(@"File: /%@ Size: %@", fileName, fileSize);
    }
}
[newPath release];
```

gary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks fine leak-wise. If you're running Xcode 3.2 you can Build->Build & Analyzer to get Clang to check this sort of thing.

Remember you only have to release things you alloc, new, copy or retain.

Consider using `stringByAppendingPathComponent`, rather than hardcoding the `@"/"` path separator. NSString has a [number of methods](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW38) like this specifically for working with paths.

```
NSString* fullPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

Comment: Hmm I tried adding [newPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/"]; to test adding a "/" to the end, but I can't seem to get it working ...

Comment: stringByAppendingPathComponent avoids you having to know about the delimiter. I've updated the answer to reflect the usage.

Comment: which delimiter to add? that's operating system dependent. which path component to add? you'd have to supply that. it's whatever would go "after" the path delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with it, although it could be better to use initWithFormat and release:

```
NSString *newPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/%@",rootPath,fileName];

// do your thing

[newPath release];
```

Comment: Not mentioned but important: That would go inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you, coming from procedural programming I am always a little cautious of declaring variables on demand (i.e. not at the start of a block) I guess I just need to be a little more flexible with a more open view with regards to Objective-C

Comment: In fact, there are very good reasons for declaring variables in the most enclosing scope possible (i.e. closest to where they are used).

Comment: You really should use the path specific methods on `NSString` to work with paths. Otherwise you can get into trouble if directories have, or do not have, trailing `'/'`, and some other corner cases. Look at the documentation for `NSString` and the methods under the _"Working With Paths"_ task group. As a bonus you get to write less code.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your code, it is correct memory management.

But it can be done with even less code and memory management needed:

```
for(fileName in [manager enumeratorAtPath:rootPath]){
  if ([[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"exr"]) {
    [fileArray addObject:fileName];

    NSString* newPath = [rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    attrDir = [manager attributesOfItemAtPath:newPath error:&myError];

    fileSize = [attrDir objectForKey: @"NSFileSize"];
    NSLog(@"File: /%@ Size: %@", fileName, fileSize);
  }
}
```